# Can't locate a button using selenium to press on it

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I've created a script in python using selenium to click on a [like button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUlBc.jpg) available in a [webpage](https://www.instagram.com/p/CBi_eIuAwbG/). I've used xpath in order to locate that button and I think I've used it correctly. However, the script doesn't seem to find that button and as a results it throws `TimeoutException` error pointing at the very line containing the xpath.

As it is not possible to hit that like button without logging in, I expect the script to get the relevant html connected to that button so that I understand I could locate it correctly.

I've tried with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

link = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CBi_eIuAwbG/"

with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)

    driver.get(link)
    item = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[./svg[@aria-label='Like']]")))
    print(item.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

> How can I locate that `like` button visible as `heart symbol` using selenium?

Comment: Note the _svg_ tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on `Like` Button induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_element_located`() and below `xpath`.

Then scroll the element into view and click.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/p/CBi_eIuAwbG/")
element=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//button[.//*[name()='svg' and @aria-label='Like']]")))
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
element.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```py
likeSVG = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'svg[aria-label="Like"]')
likeBtn = likeSVG.find_element(By.XPATH, './..')
likeBtn.click()
```

`likeBtn` is equal to the parent of the `likeSVG` div as you can use XPATH similar to file navigation commands in a CLI.

Comment: Your solution is working @Lucan. I'll surely go for it unless I get any xpath related solution. It surely deserves a plus. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `.find_element_by_xpath(xPath)` method (Uses full xpath):

```
likeXPATH = "/html/body/div[1]/section/main/div/div[1]/article/div[2]/section[1]/span[1]/button"

likeElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath(likeXPATH)

likeElement.click()
```

Comment: Sorry @Xiddoc, I'm not after `absolute xpath` which I could directly copy while inspecting element. I'm trying to create a relative one. Thanks.